# Is it possible to execute a command as another user without sudo su'ing to that user?

Tags: centos, sudo, su

I do a lot of administration in `CentOS6` for several teams. One of the more frequent things I do is sync down and package code as the team account, before deploying it out under my own account.

Is there a way to go about this without having to do a full `sudo su team_abc`? Is there a flag that will allow me to execute a specified command without exiting my current session?

caveat - these users are LDAP'd, and my account bypasses the `Enter password:` prompt when `sudo su`ing.

Comment: Try `sudo -u user`ing the command instead.

Comment: This works for commands that don't require user profile settings. So basically, it works for packaging the code but not for pulling it down since pulling the code requires env variables be set appropriately (looks like it's failing because it's still attempting to use my profile settings)

Comment: If you require user profile settings, then you want to run it in a shell with the login flag on: `sudo -u user $shell -l -c "command"`.

Comment: Hm, I just get usage errors when trying to do `sudo -u <usr>`. Either way, at this point it's probably easier to just `sudo su` and `exit` after the command completes.

Comment: (+ the -i flag to sudo )

Answer (score 2):

What you may be looking for is the setuid/setgid flag.  When set on an executable, the executable is run with the permissions of the executable's owner instead of the user making the call.

[Here's a wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)

**BE CAREFUL WITH THIS.**  If you set this on a bash script and allow write permissions on the script, you are basically allowing anyone with write permission to run any command on the system as the setuid/setgid.  you're probably better off using sudo.